# DSolve returns incorrect solution by automatically assuming positive parameters?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

The following code solves a simple 2nd-order linear ODE with real parameters $a,b$.

```
FullSimplify@
 DSolve[(a^2 - b^2) y[x] - 
    2 b^2 x (2 D[y[x], x] + x D[y[x], {x, 2}]) == 0, y[x], x]
```

The result is $$x^{-\frac{\frac{\sqrt{b^2-2 a^2} \sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}+b}{2 b}} \left(c_2 x^{\frac{\sqrt{b^2-2 a^2} \sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{b \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}}+c_1\right).$$

However, this has an obvious flaw. $b$ itself should not appear since only $b^2$ enters the original equation. The true solution is just `b` replaced by `Abs[b]`. One can remove `FullSimplify` to check. It looks as if `DSolve` sneakily assumes $b>0$.

Is it a bug? I don't think MMA usually assumes positive parameters.
A minor issue is how to really simplify those apparently cancelling square roots...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There  is no bug. The solution provided by Mathematica can easily be shown to satisfy the differential equation.

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

Using pure function (easier to verify solution)

```
eqn = (a^2 - b^2) y[x] - 2 b^2 x (2 D[y[x], x] + x D[y[x], {x, 2}]) == 0;

sol = DSolve[eqn, y, x][[1]] // FullSimplify

(* {y -> Function[{x}, 
   x^((Sqrt[-a^2 + 
       b^2] (-((Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-2 a^2 + b^2])/Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]) - (Sqrt[2] b)/
        Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2]))/(2 Sqrt[2] b)) C[1] + 
    x^((Sqrt[-a^2 + 
       b^2] ((Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-2 a^2 + b^2])/Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] - (Sqrt[2] b)/
        Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2]))/(2 Sqrt[2] b)) C[2]]} *)
```

Verifying solution

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Using function with explicit argument

```
sol2 = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x][[1]] // FullSimplify

(* {y[x] -> x^(-((b + (Sqrt[-2 a^2 + b^2] Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2])/Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])/(
    2 b))) (C[1] + 
     x^((Sqrt[-2 a^2 + b^2] Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2])/(b Sqrt[a^2 - b^2])) C[2])} *)
```

Verifying solution,

```
eqn /. (NestList[D[#, x] &, sol2, 2] // Flatten // Simplify) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Verifying that solutions are equivalent

```
(y[x] /. sol) == (y[x] /. sol2) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

There are no assumptions about `b`. `a` and `b` can even be complex

```
(eqn /. {a -> c + I*d, b -> e + I*f}) /. (sol /. {a -> c + I*d, 
     b -> e + I*f}) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You’re right. I suddenly realized it’s a silly question regarding somewhat a coincidence. BTW, do you think MMA assumes real or complex parameters here?

Comment: Mathematica assumes variables are complex unless told otherwise or the context is implicitly real (e.g., probability distributions).

Comment: It would be useful to verify the solution for concrete values of the parameters (in particular, taking $b$ negative) because there is a chance that the above simplifications are formal (i.e. the simplifications don't take into account branches of the roots).

Comment: @user64494 - If you find a counter example, recommend that you post a question concerning that example. Note that any such example must allow for the arbitrary constants being arbitrary complex values.

Answer (score 2):

$\left(a^2-b^2\right) y(x)-2 b^2 x \left(x y''(x)+2 y'(x)\right)=0$ is an Euler-type DE so substituting $y = x^r$ into the DE we get $x^r \left(a^2-b^2 (2 r (r+1)+1)\right)=0$ and solving for $r$ we get $r = \frac{\pm\sqrt{2 a^2 b^2-b^4}-b^2}{2 b^2}$ or $r = \{-\frac 12\left(\sqrt{2(\frac ab)^2-1}+1\right),\frac 12\left(\sqrt{2(\frac ab)^2-1}-1\right)\}$ so the general solution is $y=C_1 x^{-\frac 12\left(\sqrt{2(\frac ab)^2-1}+1\right)}+C_2 x^{\frac 12\left(\sqrt{2(\frac ab)^2-1}-1\right)}$. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed as follows.

```
$Assumptions =  a^2 > b^2;
Expand[FullSimplify[DSolve[(a^2 - b^2) y[x] -2 b^2 x (2 D[y[x], x] + x D[y[x], {x, 2}]) == 0, y[x], x]]]
```

> $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to c_1 x^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{\frac{2 a^2}{b^2}-1}-1\right)}+c_2 x^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{\frac{2 a^2}{b^2}-1}-1\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2 a^2}{b^2}-1}}\right\}\right\}  $$

```
$Assumptions = a^2 < b^2; Expand[FullSimplify[DSolve[(a^2 - b^2) y[x] - 2 b^2 x (2 D[y[x], x] + x D[y[x], {x, 2}]) == 0, y[x], x]]]
```

> $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to c_1 x^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{\frac{2 a^2}{b^2}-1}-1\right)}+c_2 x^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{\frac{2 a^2}{b^2}-1}-1\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2 a^2}{b^2}-1}}\right\}\right\} $$